# How to read/write excel checkbox status in c++

Tags: c++, excel, com, ole

I am working on an issue that requires me to read/write status of a checkbox in a given cell in Excel.

I know that you can access activeX controls can be accessed using COM/OLE. However, I have not been able to find any solution to this problem. In fact, I am not even sure if you can access checkbox using row-column. I studied the properties of activeX checkbox. Found top and left properties, but not row-column

I want to ask if:
1. Is there any direct way to do this.
2. If not, any indirect way, say getting the top/left column somehow and then getting row/column positions and comparing the two.
3. Is there any way to do the same with form controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to all for your replies. I found something useful on MSDN. Have edited it a bit and sharing with you.. Thanks for your support everyone

(Forgive the formatting)

Autowrap() function from msdn is completely unedited:

```
HRESULT AutoWrap(int autoType, VARIANT *pvResult, IDispatch *pDisp, LPOLESTR ptName, int cArgs...) {
// Begin variable-argument list...
va_list marker;
va_start(marker, cArgs);

if(!pDisp) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "NULL IDispatch passed to AutoWrap()", "Error", 0x10010);
    _exit(0);
}

// Variables used...
DISPPARAMS dp = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
DISPID dispidNamed = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
DISPID dispID;
HRESULT hr;
char buf[200];
char szName[200];


// Convert down to ANSI
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ptName, -1, szName, 256, NULL, NULL);

// Get DISPID for name passed...
hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &ptName, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispID);
if(FAILED(hr)) {
    sprintf(buf, "IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames(\"%s\") failed w/err 0x%08lx", szName, hr);
    MessageBox(NULL, buf, "AutoWrap()", 0x10010);
    _exit(0);
    return hr;
}

// Allocate memory for arguments...
VARIANT *pArgs = new VARIANT[cArgs+1];
// Extract arguments...
for(int i=0; i<cArgs; i++) {
    pArgs[i] = va_arg(marker, VARIANT);
}

// Build DISPPARAMS
dp.cArgs = cArgs;
dp.rgvarg = pArgs;

// Handle special-case for property-puts!
if(autoType & DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT) {
    dp.cNamedArgs = 1;
    dp.rgdispidNamedArgs = &dispidNamed;
}

// Make the call!
hr = pDisp->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, autoType, &dp, pvResult, NULL, NULL);
if(FAILED(hr)) {
    sprintf(buf, "IDispatch::Invoke(\"%s\"=%08lx) failed w/err 0x%08lx", szName, dispID, hr);
    MessageBox(NULL, buf, "AutoWrap()", 0x10010);
    _exit(0);
    return hr;
}
// End variable-argument section...
va_end(marker);

delete [] pArgs;

return hr;
}
```

Here is the edited main() function:

```
int main()
{
 // Initialize COM for this thread...
   CoInitialize(NULL);

   // Get CLSID for our server...
   CLSID clsid;
   HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Excel.Application", &clsid);

   if(FAILED(hr)) {

      ::MessageBox(NULL, "CLSIDFromProgID() failed", "Error", 0x10010);
      return -1;
   }

   // Start server and get IDispatch...
   IDispatch *pXlApp;
   hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pXlApp);

   if(FAILED(hr)) {
      ::MessageBox(NULL, "Excel not registered properly", "Error", 0x10010);
      return -2;
   }

   // Make it visible (i.e. app.visible = 1)
   {
      VARIANT x;
      x.vt = VT_I4;
      x.lVal = 1;
      AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pXlApp, L"Visible", 1, x);
   }

   // Make it visible (i.e. app.visible = 1)
   {
      VARIANT x;
      x.vt = VT_BSTR;
      x.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString (L"D:\\");
      AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pXlApp, L"DefaultFilePath", 1, x);
   }

   // Get Workbooks collection
   IDispatch *pXlBooks;
   {
      VARIANT result;
  VariantInit(&result);
  AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlApp, L"Workbooks", 0);
  pXlBooks = result.pdispVal;
   }

   // Call Workbooks.Add() to get a new workbook...
   IDispatch *pXlBook;
   {
      VARIANT parm;
  parm.vt = VT_BSTR;
  parm.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"a.xlsx");

  VARIANT result;
  VariantInit(&result);
  AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pXlBooks, L"Open", 1,parm);
  pXlBook = result.pdispVal;
    }

   // Get ActiveSheet object
   IDispatch *pXlSheet;
   {
enter code here
  VARIANT result;
  VariantInit(&result);
  AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlBook, L"ActiveSheet",0);
  if(result.pdispVal != NULL)
    pXlSheet = result.pdispVal;
   }

   //Get shapes collection..
    IDispatch *pShapes;
    {
       VARIANT result;
   VariantInit(&result);
   AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlSheet, L"Shapes",0);
   pShapes = result.pdispVal;
}

int nControls;  
{
   VARIANT result;
   VariantInit(&result);
   AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pShapes, L"Count",0);
   if(result.vt == VT_I4)
       nControls = result.lVal;
}

for(int i = 1; i <= nControls; ++i) {

    IDispatch * pShape;

    {  
        VARIANT x;
        x.vt = VT_I4;
        x.lVal = i;

        VARIANT result;
        VariantInit(&result);
        AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pShapes, L"Item",1, x);
        pShape = result.pdispVal;
    }   

    IDispatch *pControlFormat = NULL;
    {
        VARIANT result;
        VariantInit(&result);
        AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pShape, L"Type",0);

        // msoFormControl
        if(result.lVal == 8)
        {
            VARIANT result0;
            VariantInit(&result0);
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result0, pShape, L"FormControlType",0);

            // xlCheckBox
            if(result0.lVal == 1) {

                // Get range containing cell to be tested
                VARIANT result2;
                VariantInit(&result2);
                IDispatch * range;
                {
                    VARIANT param1;
                    param1.vt= VT_BSTR;
                    param1.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"F5");

                    VARIANT result3;
                    VariantInit(&result3);
                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result3, pXlSheet,L"Range",1,param1);
                    range = result3.pdispVal;
                }

                // Get the top, left, bottom, right of cell
                DOUBLE top, left, bottom, right;
                {
                    VARIANT result4;
                    VariantInit(&result4);

                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result4, range,L"Top",0);
                    top = result4.dblVal;

                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result4, range,L"Left",0);
                    left = result4.dblVal;

                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result4, range,L"Height",0);
                    bottom = top + result4.dblVal;

                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result4, range,L"Width",0);
                    right = left + result4.dblVal;
                }
                range->Release();

                // Get the top, left of checkbox
                FLOAT shapetop, shapeleft;
                {
                    VARIANT result5;
                    VariantInit(&result5);

                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result5, pShape,L"Top",0);
                    shapetop = result5.fltVal;

                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result5, pShape,L"Left",0);
                    shapeleft = result5.fltVal;
                }

                // Get hold of control format
                VARIANT result1;
                VariantInit(&result1);
                AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result1, pShape, L"ControlFormat",0);
                pControlFormat = result1.pdispVal;



                // Check if the checkbox if within the range boundary. If yes, then check it, else dont
                if((top <= shapetop) && (bottom >= shapetop) && (left <= shapeleft) && (right >= shapeleft)) {

                    // Perpare the parameter
                    VARIANT parm;
                    VARIANT_BOOL t = VARIANT_TRUE;;
                    parm.vt = VT_BOOL;
                    parm.pboolVal = &t;

                    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pControlFormat, L"Value", 1, parm);
                }                   
            }
        }
    }

    if(pControlFormat != NULL) pControlFormat->Release();
    pShape->Release();
}

   // to save when we tell Excel to quit...
   {
       VARIANT x;
  x.vt = VT_I4;
  x.lVal = 1;
  AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pXlBook, L"Save", 0);
    }

   // Wait for user...
   ::MessageBox(NULL, "All done.", "Notice", 0x10000);

   // Tell Excel to quit (i.e. App.Quit)
   AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pXlApp, L"Quit", 0);

   // Release references...

   pShapes->Release();

   pXlSheet->Release();
   pXlBook->Release();
   pXlBooks->Release();
   pXlApp->Release();


   // Uninitialize COM for this thread...
   CoUninitialize();

   return 0;
}
```

For further details: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb149081%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Despite appearances, checkboxes are not contained by the spreadsheet; they are painted on top of it. So they don't know anything about rows or columns and you can't refer to them that way.

The checkboxes are held in the `OLEObjects` collection. This example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178183%28v=office.12%29.aspx) should give you the information you need:

```
Private Sub chkFinished_Click()
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that checkbox's are "in cells", there are a couple of ways (that i can think of) that you can get the value.

First: Dont check the value of the checkbox, check the value of its linked cell (if its assigned)

Second: Using something like the following pseudo-code to determine which control is where.

```
ForEach Sheet.Controls As Control
  If Control.Type = Checkbox Then
    Row = 1
    YPos = 0
    Do
      If YPos + Sheet.Rows(Row).RowHeight > Control.Top Then
        Exit Do
      Else
        YPos = YPos + Sheets.Rows(Row).RowHeight
      End If
    Loop
    Column = 1
    XPos = 0
    Do
      If XPos + Sheet.Columns(Column).ColumnWidth > Control.Left Then
        Exit Do
      Else
        XPos = XPos + Sheets.Columns(Column).ColumnWidth
      End If
    Loop
    Debug.Print Control.Name & " is in Cell(" & XPos & ", " & YPos & ")"
  End If
End ForEach
```

Comment: Hi @nick, i appreciate your help with the algorithm.. as u see i mentioned a similar technique in my question. What i am looking for is some help regarding COM in c++. Can you help me with the messages used to get the above algorithm running? I have not been able to find anything relevant myself..

Comment: I've never really used com so not sure. Are you using excel interop ? My code will only run in your head, as is pseudo-code. I assume c++ has some sort of object library like VBA? You'll need to look through the available objects for the controls collection and stuff to do with the row height and width.